# FileSystemWatcher and Hidden Share

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a hidden share:

```
  \\computername\Logs$
```

And I need to monitor file changes in that share.
I've decided to use FileSystemWatcher Class, but it doesn't raise any events. And it doesn't show any errors to me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  FileWatcher fw = new FileWatcher(@"\\computername\Logs$", "*.*");
  fw.Start();
}

class FileWatcher(string filePath, string mask)
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher;
  watcher.Path = filePath;
  watcher.Filter = mask;
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
  watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
  watcher.Error += OnError;

  public void Start()
  {
    watcher.InternalBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Watcher Started");

    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
  }

  private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File Changed");
  }

  private void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
  }
}
```

Does FileSystemWatcher work properly with hidden shares?

Comment: Add an event handler to the `Error` event and check the `GetException() ` method of the `ErrorEventArgs`. There have been in the past known issues with network shares and adjusting the internal buffer size. In earlier frameworks the exception reported would be incorrect, though with newer ones  that should be corrected (I think?)

Comment: I've added event handler to the Error in my code (actually I've already had it in my project, just corrected it here), but it still doesn't write any errors. It tells me "Watcher Started" in console and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not compile ,maybe you had errors while copy the code
and where the event handler Watcher_Changed, maybe you have mistake and put Watcher_Created instead

Comment: yes, I've mistaken and put Watcher_Created instead Watcher_Changed while copying code here. But it still doesn't work with hidden shares, but it perfectly works with local folders or shared folders.